# git rebase conflict merging wrong files

Tags: git, merge, conflict, rebase, corruption

I have what I think is a really strange problem with merge conflicts during a rebase.

I'm trying to rebase a feature branch with a development branch:

```
git checkout myFeatureBranch
git rebase developBranch
```

Now git rebase reports conflicts and I have to use git mergetool to resolve conflicts.

```
git mergetool
```

Git mergetool declares a conflicted file `myFile1.h` and the merge interface opens (the problem occurs on either Linux or Windows/tortoisegit for the same repo). What I see is that the "theirs" file is completely the wrong file `myOtherFile.c` although the "mine" file is correctly showing `myFile1.h`.

I've tried `git gc --aggressive` and `git fsck --full`. git gc reports no problems at all and git fsck has a lot of dangling stuff but no errors or missing information.

Is this some kind of corruption in the git database and if so, can it be repaired?

Any other possibilities for what is wrong?

I did think that perhaps I could merge the "mine" file back onto itself (ignoring all the incorrect "theirs" changes completely), and maybe this would clean up the problem, but I fear it could also make things worse.

Whatever the problem is, it does appear to be in our master remote repo as new clones exhibit the same rebase problem.

Thanks for your help.

`git config -l` output with some redaction:

```
core.symlinks=false
core.autocrlf=input
color.diff=auto
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=true
pack.packsizelimit=2g
help.format=html
http.sslcainfo=/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
sendemail.smtpserver=/bin/msmtp.exe
diff.astextplain.textconv=astextplain
rebase.autosquash=true
core.autocrlf=true
core.excludesfile=<global exclude file>
user.name=Russell
user.email=<email address>
push.default=simple
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=false
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.symlinks=false
core.ignorecase=true
core.hidedotfiles=dotGitOnly
remote.origin.url=<gituser@gitserver>
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.puttykeyfile=<key.ppk>
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
branch.develop.remote=origin
branch.develop.merge=refs/heads/develop
branch.myFeatureBranch.remote=origin
branch.myFeatureBranch.merge=refs/heads/myFeatureBranch
```

Comment: please post `git config -l` output

Comment: Added git config output to original post.

Comment: Since fsck was happy there was never a chance this is database corruption, and there's nothing wrong in the config. What was the exact rebase command you gave? And, any chance you can publish the repo or make a publishable testcase? (also, which mergetool)

Comment: The exact rebase command was `git rebase develop`. The mergetool is meld in Linux, tortoisemerge in Windows. I can't publish the repo. I thought about making a test case but at the moment I don't have any ideas on how to reproduce the problem; I'll have to think about that one.

Comment: One thing - do you have merges in your history? Try `rebase -p`.

Comment: `rebase -p` seemed to do the trick. Why would merges in the history make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git rebase -p develop` seemed to do the trick. Thanks to [jthill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290731/jthill).

I haven't yet tried [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s answer, but I plan to explore that as well, out of curiosity.

Comment: wow, that did the trick for a similar issue for me to when the files were moved into the wrong folder

Answer (score 6):

You're running into git's rename detection.

First, some important notes about rebase.

1. Rebase uses the merge machinery.
2. In a merge (e.g., merging `feature` into `master`) you would say "the branch I am on, `master`, is ‘our’ code and the branch I am merging-in, `feature`, is ‘their’ code".

When you rebase code, the "ours" side is the code you are rebasing *to*, and the "theirs" code is the code you are rebasing—i.e., your own code.  In effect, the "sides" are swapped.  (See the `-m`, `-s`, and `-X` arguments to `git rebase` and the note about sides being swapped.)

Inside the merge machinery, using the default (`recursive`) strategy, git thinks "our" `myFile1.h` (i.e., the one from `develop`) is more similar to "their" `myOtherFile.c` (i.e., your own version of that file) than to "their" (i.e., your) `myFile1.h`.  So it's trying to merge the wrong files.

Moving over to the `git merge` documentation, note the options you can pass to `recursive`.  The most important one is probably `rename-threshold=<n>`.  So, you can pass `-X rename-threshold=100` (or any number sufficiently higher than 50).  I have never actually run into this issue myself but that seems like it should do the trick.

Comment: the swapping is easy to understand if you remember how rebasing works: you're resetting your `feature` branch to match `develop`, then cherry-picking each commit in the original branch.  so the commits that lived on `feature` are actually the "foreign" ones.

Answer (score 0):

> [Why would merges in the history make any difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659937/git-rebase-conflict-merging-wrong-files#comment29234057_19659937)

Rebase is a noise-reduction tool to keep timewasting redundancies out of pu{bli,}shed history. Once you've done what deserves to be written, `rebase` is the "write what deserves to be read" helper.  For a blow-by-blow you'd just merge, when that would unnecessarily complicate readers' jobs a linear[ized] one-for-one is almost always good enough and easy, so that's what rebase tries for by default. If it turns out not so easy, there's `-i` and `-p`, `--interactive` and `--preserve-merges`, to help with the more intricate editing.